# How to activate @MultipartConfig annotation on a JSP file?

Tags: jsp, file-upload

so in my class i was ordered to upload images to database and get them out and show them on a website, pretty simple when using servlet or php, but i was asked to do it using only JSP files. to do so i had to get an image from the user and pass it as a parameter and get a part of the parameter, not a problem.

the problem started when i tried to run it and the server asked for @multipartconfig annotation. i cant find a way to add it to the jsp code.

### this is the jsp:

```
    <%@page import="javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="java.io.InputStream"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>


<%
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    Part p = request.getPart("image");
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    if (p != null) {
        inputStream = p.getInputStream();
    }

    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test42";
    Class.forName(driver);
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "1234");

    String sqlString = "INSERT INTO test42.images items(idimages) values(" + inputStream + ");";

    String msg = p.toString();

%>
```

### this is the upload form:

```
  <form method="post" action="mainPage.jsp" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                choose file :
                <input type="file" name="image" />

                <input type="submit" value="submit">
            </form>
```

and this is the messege from the server:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request.getPart is called without multipart configuration. Either add a @MultipartConfig to the servlet, or a multipart-config element to web.xml
```

i tried adding it to the web.xml but it didnt work....
the app just crash with a build error;
i got this solution from here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gmhal.html

### like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
   </session-config>

   <multipart-config>
    <location>/tmp</location>
    <max-file-size>20848820</max-file-size>
    <max-request-size>418018841</max-request-size>
    <file-size-threshold>1048576</file-size-threshold>
</multipart-config>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Putting code in scriptlets in a JSP is bad practice - put Java code in for example a servlet or some other Java class instead of in a JSP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<multipart-config>` tag needs to go inside the `<servlet>` tag and you need to have a `<servlet-mapping>` along the `<servlet>` tag.

```xml
<servlet>   
    <servlet-name>uploadfile</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/mainPage.jsp</jsp-file>
    <multipart-config>
        <location>/temp</location>
        <max-file-size>20848820</max-file-size>
        <max-request-size>418018841</max-request-size>
        <file-size-threshold>1048576</file-size-threshold>
    </multipart-config>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>uploadfile</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/mainPage.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: the JSP file is actually called a servlet? i thought a servlet is only a java file with a class that extends httpservlet..

Answer (score 0):

Actually every jsp file will be converted to servlet because tomcat can only address servlet and so every jsp file is indirectly a servlet and has all the features of it

Comment: How this answer the question which is how to fix the exception? Can you add more context/explanation to your answer