# How do I make a JSP page to upload an image to a MySQL database?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, file-upload

I have a web project written in JSP with a couple of Java classes for the back-end. I want to make a page where the user uploads an image and this gets saved in a database.

I have a page where the user uploads the image, with a form like this:

```
<form action="UploadImage.jsp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload Image">
```

I want to have my UploadImage.jsp file save this image to a LongBLOB object in a MySQL database. I tried using request.getParameter(), and request.getPart(), but they both return null, and any attempts to use these results in a NullPointerException.

I've tried looking online, but all the solutions involve using a servlet, instead of a JSP page. And yes, I know using JSP is not best practice, but for the purposes of this project, it's what I have to use.

Comment: You really don't want to store an image directly in your MySQL database. You're far better off saving the path to the image, and just loading the image when you need it.

Comment: Where would I store the image otherwise? I've seen multiple answers online saying this, but I have no idea of any other way of doing this.

Comment: http://www.codejava.net/coding/upload-files-to-database-servlet-jsp-mysql This perhaps

Comment: So, you have a webserver that serves these jsp's right? That's where you make a folder with images, and then you store the name or the full path to the image.

Comment: @SnazzyWolf Yes, I saw that, but it uses a servlet instead of JSP for the uploading part, unfortunately.

Comment: @FMashiro Okay, thank you for the advice! Unfortunately, I can't even seem to get an image to save - whether to a database or to a server...

Comment: Have you looked into using an instance of ServletFileUpload and using the parseRequest method within your UploadImage.jsp code? That's how I would handle it. I would create a new File object and save the image on the server side and inside the database just save the path location to where it is on the server.

Comment: @Mayron Could you please elaborate on that? That does sound like what I would want to do. How would I use that in a JSP page?

Comment: you can write your request handling and saving part in jsp using scriptlet. take the reference given by @SnazzyWolf. Write the content of dopost inside scriptlet. It should work as jsp gets translated into servlet.

Comment: @SangamBelose How would I go about adding the MultipartConfig annotation to the JSP, though?

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37965890/add-annotation-to-jsp

Comment: @SangamBelose Does that mean I absolutely have to use a servlet for this task?

Comment: Using servlet is preferred. but you can do it using jsp. Please configure the multipart config in web.xml.

Comment: @NeilBanerjee sorry, I was on my lunch break. Just added an answer but you'll have to test it. I know that it is possible to handle image uploads using this method as I have used this in the past. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the

Part p=request.getpart("file");

inputstream is=p.getinputstream(p);

byte[] b=Ioutils.getBytes(is);

Then You can use Setbytes to stored in mysql

And you also declared the multipart annotations on your servlet before class name

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ServletFileUpload class to parse the request and upload multiple files, in your case the image, to a temp directory on the server and then you'll just need to store the file's location as a path in the database.

```
ServletContext context = pageContext.getServletContext();    
String filePath = "c:\\apache-tomcat\\webapps\\images\\";

DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();      
factory.setRepository(new File("c:\\temp"));
ServletFileUpload uploader = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

try { 
    List files = upload.parseRequest(request);
    Iterator<FileItem> iter = fileItems.iterator();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        FileItem file = iter.next();            
        File serverFile = new File(filePath + 
            file.getName().substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")));            
        file.write(serverFile);
    }
} catch(Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
}
```

Comment: Not tested it myself yet! But just to demonstrate how it works.