# method extractFileName(Part) is undefined for the type JSP (Full code)

Tags: java, jsp, web, web-deployment

I'm working on a small project where I'm trying to dd profile so the user can upload his profile pic so while I was searching for references I found some Youtube videos and I started coding and I want to link the image which user uploaded as his profile image. There I'm getting the error "The method extractFileName(Part) is undefined for the type"(in jsp)

```
  <%@page 
       import="java.sql.*,java.text.*,javax.servlet.*, 
       java.security.MessageDigest,java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException 
       ,java.io.File,java.io.PrintWriter,java.awt.List 
     ,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.Paths,javax.servlet.http.Part"%> 

     <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
       pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%!
%>
<%
String username=(String) session.getAttribute("nkey");
String f_name =request.getParameter("f_name");
String l_name =request.getParameter("l_name");

javax.servlet.http.Part part =request.getPart("profile_link");
String id_link =request.getParameter("id_link");
String age =request.getParameter("age");
String gender =request.getParameter("gender");
String address =request.getParameter("address");
String pincode =request.getParameter("pincode");
String qualification =request.getParameter("qualification");
String year =request.getParameter("year");
String college_name =request.getParameter("college_name");
String state =request.getParameter("state");
String country =request.getParameter("country");
%>
<%!
private static final String SAVE_DIR="Pictures";
%>
<%response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");%>
<% 
PrintWriter outt=response.getWriter();
String savePath="C:/Users/thots/Desktop/My World/internsip/Student_Portal 2.0/WebContent"+File.separator+SAVE_DIR;
File fileSaveDir=new File(savePath);

String fileName=extractFileName(part);(error here)

part.write(savePath + File.separator + fileName);

String filePath=savePath+File.separator + fileName;     
%>
<%
try 
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Student_Portal 2.0","root","");
    Statement st=con.createStatement();
    int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into student_details values('"+username+"','"+f_name+"','"+l_name+"','"+filePath+"','"+id_link+"','"+age+"','"+gender+"','"+address+"','"+pincode+"','"+qualification+"','"+year+"','"+college_name+"','"+state+"','"+country+"')");
    if(i>0)
    {
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
        Statement stt=con.createStatement();
        String sql="update user_login set P_Status='1' where username='"+username+"'";
        stt.executeUpdate(sql);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Failed");
    }

} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
```

Html code

```
<form action="add_student_details.jsp" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div>
                                    <label for="img">Upload Profile Picture</label>
                                     <input name="profile_link" type="file" class="form-control" required>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div>
                                    <label for="img">Upload Your ID card</label>
                                    <input name="id_link" type="file" class="form-control" required>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-6">
                                     <input name="f_name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    <input name="l_name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-6">
                                     <input name="age" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Age" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6">
                                      <select name="gender" class="form-control" required>
                                        <option>Male</option>
                                        <option >Female</option>
                                      </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div>
                                <textarea name="address" rows="4" cols="55" placeholder="Your Address" id="w3review" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div>
                                <input name="pincode" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Pincode" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                        <br>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                         <h4>Educational Info</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                          <select name="qualification" class="form-control" required>
                                          <option selected disabled>Select Your Qualification</option>
                                            <option>B.Tech</option>
                                            <option >B.E</option>
                                          </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                          <select name="year" class="form-control" required>
                                          <option selected disabled>Select Your Year</option>
                                            <option>I</option>
                                            <option >II</option>
                                            <option>III</option>
                                            <option >IV</option>
                                          </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                <div >
                                          <select name="college_name" class="form-control" required>
                                          <option selected disabled>Select Your College</option>
                                            <option>ABCD College Of Engineering And Technology</option>
                                            <option >XYZ College Of Engineering And Technology</option>
                                          </select>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                          <select name="state" class="form-control" required>
                                          <option selected disabled>Select Your State</option>
                                            <option>Telangana</option>
                                            <option >Kerala</option>
                                          </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                          <select name="country" class="form-control" required>
                                          <option selected disabled>Select Your Country</option>
                                            <option>India</option>
                                            <option>United States</option>
                                          </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                <hr>
                                <center>
                                <button type="submit" class="submit-btn">Submit</button>
                                </center>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                       </form>
```

Sorry for sharing the whole code. i tried multiple ways but none worked for me someone please help me Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the mentioned method `String extractFilename(HttpPart part)` within your JSP inside `<%!  %>`, similar to sample implementation provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30818994/13279831)

```
<%!
String extractFilename(Part part) {
    final String partHeader = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
    for (String content : part.getHeader("content-disposition").split(";")) {
        if (content.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
            return content.substring(
                    content.indexOf('=') + 1).trim().replace("\"", "");
        }
    }
    return null;   
}  
%>
```

Comment: at line 2 HttpPart error(Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - HttpPart cannot be resolved 
  to a type)

Comment: It had to be `Part` for sure :)

Comment: sorry I didn't get u as im a beginner im facing this issue from the morning but unable to resolve please help me Thank you

Comment: Which issue do you get now?

Comment: i sucesfully added the method
when i run on server 
Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/Student_Portal_2.0] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
I'm getting this issue now

Comment: NullPointer occurs inside `extractFilename` method?

Comment: yes si resolved that issue sir how can we add @MultipartConfig in jsp?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow you.  As I understand, the issue with undefined method is resolved successfully.  If you encounter other issue (NullPointerException) please try to debug it and identify which object is missing and thus causing this exception.  If you cannot fix it by yourselves, feel free to open a new question and provide a relevant stacktrace of this issue.  Best regards!

Comment: Please check this link how to enable [@MultipartConfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37965890/add-annotation-to-jsp/37970429) for JSP.